# How to toggle a bit of a number without using XOR operator?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I know how to do it using xor. I need a solution without using xor

Comment: If you know the definition of XOR you can duplicate it using AND and OR.  This sounds like a test question (are you in the middle of a test) or a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

use `~` operator:

```
int b = 0;
int a = ~b;
```